# Is there any project/set of libraries that make it easy to comunicate between various programming languages/platforms?

Tags: python, haskell, interop, jvm, communication

I'm just finishing a relatively big project in scala and will start another related one soon.

I haven't chosen the language yet and would like my decision to be based more on features of the language or available libraries than interoperability concerns.

And this is the reason to ask this.

My requirements are (top is more important):

1. interoperability between various programming languages/platforms (probable ones are JVM, Haskell, Python, C/C++)
2. easy to prototype/refactor
3. easy to program
4. performant without much concern for optimization on my part (this may exclude using files)

Comment: *is there any obvious general way to comunicate between various programming languages/platforms?* How about HTTP? You may need to be a little more specific.

Comment: Why do you exactly need to interop between many different languages?

Comment: you could use sockets and define your own protocol, maybe using some widely supported serialization library like [JSON](http://www.json.org)

Comment: The only thing I can thing I can think of is TCP/IP and a unique communications protocol, specific enough for your application and general enough you could use it again. You'd either have to find a common implementation language for the protocol to to which each language could interface, or write a native implementation in each language. This almost sounds like you need to look for a product.

Comment: @MattH and (a)wvd I'm not being more specific because I haven't started anything and haven't made any choices. Either way, from my previous experience, I've seen that I spend much more time implementing requirements than the interfaces among modules (I've used REST and RMI/CORBA). So, I would like to have the freedom to choose the language, platform or set of libraries that best answer my requirements. PyQt for GUIs, Haskell or C++ for mathematics (for different reasons), Scala (JVM) because that's what I know best and will make me faster coder for many different tasks, etc.

Comment: One more detail, My next project is research oriented and there is already a great amount of libraries and complete programs that do a lot of work for me. The "problem" is, they are written in different languages and platforms. And I don't want to focus on rewriting everything in my language of choice if I can reuse.

Comment: Why was this question closed? I read the FAQ and I believe I've given enough detail to make it easy to choose "correct answer". But since the asker if often a bad judge of the quality of it's question, I would appreciate some feedback to improve it.

Comment: @MattH I'm starting to understand why this question was closed. HTTP is a good answer but I was looking more for specific projects that make it easier to code the communication layer. I changed the quesiton accordingly.

Comment: *My requirements are simple* - I'd like the moon on the stick. Your requirements aren't simple or well defined. *easy to program*, highly subjective and argumentative to decide. *performant without much concern for optimization on my part*, any idiot can ruin performance if they don't know what they are doing.

Comment: @MattH Point taken. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to communicate between programs written in various languages and distributed across various platforms is to use a [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) library.

ZeroMQ is one of my favourite due to its simplicity, speed, and the availability of bindings for a significant number of languages: http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:_start

You could also use ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, or whatever else you come across that has bindings in several languages.

Answer (score 2):

I do almost all of my communication via [Redis](http://redis.io/), its amazingly simple to move data between languages accurately and quickly. Its a simple key/store database that allows me to do this in python and

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis()
r.set("a", 33)
```

And then, almost the same code in java (minus the massive initialization because java is verbose)

```
r.get("a"); // in java
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to be a pretty good solution. Redis is implemented in Python, Java and Haskell so it exactly fits your choice. Only C++ just would take a little bit of extra work.

Comment: Most of a working implementation is here https://github.com/mrpi/redis-cplusplus-client
See other clients here http://redis.io/clients

Answer (score 2):

+1 to message passing, especially if the library will defer delivery when the recipient is unavailable.  If you decide to use messaging, you will need to define a messaging protocol.  One good choice is [Representational State Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) (ReST) which, despite its name, is a stateless, message-based interaction protocol based on HTTP.  It requires extremely careful API definition, which is, in itself, a Very Good Thing.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I use ReST extensively but, I'm looking for something that makes it a bit easier to prototype. Maybe I should add the "prototype" as a requirement. Good suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways, but they split into three main options:

1. Use some kind of centralised communication node (Message Queue, Key-Value store, maybe database);
2. Cross-platform distributed object technology (like CORBA);
3. HTTP using whatever web-services approach you like (although most people not brainwashed by the Enterprise Borg like restful webservices of various sorts), directly between components.

I would ignore 2 (it never turns out to be that easy).

As to 1, note that databases should generally not be used as a fake message-passing platform. Only use this if it really is all about storing datasets. Note also that http://redis.io is a message queue AND key-value store.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the splitting into three main ways to do it. Thinking like this makes it much easier to reason about the problem.